# Wildcard character in CHECK in Create table taken as string

Tags: sql, string, character, wildcard

I created an info table that stores employee record, the SQL query for it as follows...

```
CREATE TABLE info1 (
   empid VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT empchk 
      CHECK (empid IN ('kh\%' ESCAPE '\''),
   initials CHAR(6), fname CHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
   lname CHAR(25), 
   userstatus INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   designation CHAR(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Now, as you can see constraint in `empid` is `kh%` where - as far as I remember - `%` means that any number of the following characters (limited to `8` of course) can be anything, right?

I am using Java DB and strangely it has taken the `%` symbol also to be a part of the string so if I enter `khce0001`, it says `empchk` violation, it only takes in `kh%`

What should I do? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in this SQL query is that I have used `IN` instead of `LIKE` (which I believe does wildcard checking), so

- I dropped the constraint with...

  ```
  ALTER TABLE info DROP CONSTRAINT empchk;
  ```
- and altered the table with...

  ```
  ALTER TABLE info ADD CONSTRAINT empchk CHECK (empid LIKE ('kh%'));
  ```
- and hence the correct SQL Query should have been...

  ```
  CREATE TABLE info1 (
      empid VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT empchk 
          CHECK (empid LIKE ('kh%')),
      initials CHAR(6), 
      fname CHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      lname CHAR(25), 
      userstatus INTEGER NOT NULL,
      designation CHAR(20) NOT NULL
  );
  ```

Comment: good that you were able to figure out. consider closing the question